How will the monsoons work in this boomerang-shaped supercontinent?
Back and forth, I have created a fantasy supercontinent shaped in the likeness of an asymmetrical boomerang, with its elbow enlarged to resemble a fish’s head pointing westward, its lifting arm long and narrow and its dingle arm short and broad.  The supercontinent makes up 35-and-a-half percent of the planet’s surface.  On Earth, that would translate to the size of the Indian Ocean.  However, its shape means that it extends from 83 degrees North to 90 degrees South.
This supercontinent has three major mountain ranges.  The highest is a range of Andes-like volcanoes that line up the entire western coastline, from pole to pole.  For the moment, let's imagine its highest peak to be as high as Everest.  The second-highest mountains are a continent-continent collision range (like the Himalayas), as high as the Andes.  Behind them is a Tibet-like plateau.  The shortest mountains, another continent-continent collision range, connect the lifting arm to the elbow.  They stand as high as Denali.  They have their own accompanying Tibet-like plateau.
Mentioning the plateaus is crucial because during the summer, these uplands soak up sunlight and draw in nearby sea air.  On Earth, that is how India bathes in the great rains of the monsoon.
In the event that this might be helpful to formulate an answer, let's talk a little bit about the world the supercontinent is set in.  It is set within a quaternary system clumped into two binaries—a Parent Binary in which the planet orbits and a Grandparent Binary.  The Parent Binary comprises of one star 105 percent as wide, 110 as massive and 126 as bright as our sun orbiting one that is 130 percent as wide, 170 as massive and six times as bright as our sun.  The Grandparent Binary has a B0 star (740 percent as wide, 18 times as massive and 20,000 times as bright as our sun) orbiting an O2 star (12 times as wide, 100 times as massive and 800,000 times as bright as our sun).  (Stellar lifespan won't provide a relevant answer to the upcoming question.)  The one concern that is relevant to that scenario is that there is an awful lot of radiation to deal with.  Because the Parent Binary orbits the Grandparent Binary, the habitable zones, the spaces in which liquid surface water is possible, of both binaries overlap.  This would bathe the planet in so much radiation that life can’t thrive at all.  As protection (and a key note to influence the answer since we're talking about a greenhouse gas), the planet’s ozone layer is one inch thick.  This doesn’t sound like much, but the truth is, that is actually eight times thicker than Earth’s ozone layer.  Also, whereas our magnetic field measures anywhere between 0.25 and 0.65 gauss, this world’s magnetic field tops in at 12 gauss.
The arrangement of this world’s solar system results in such a massive clash of gravity that the planet’s orbital shape is extremely elliptical.  Usually, the farthest point of the ellipsis is where we’d get an orbital winter, thus making it the longest and most hostile season, but because it orbits a binary that orbits another, orbital winter on this world behaves an awful lot like our summer.  During orbital winter, the Grandparent Binary shares the night sky with the moon.  At the same season, it would be so far away from the Parent Binary that daylight is nothing more than 24 hours of twilight.  But during the shortest orbital season, summer, all four stars are on the day sky, and only the moon dominates the nightscape.
Due to the elliptical orbit, this world’s seasons are asymmetrical.  One day lasts 48 hours, twice as long as on Earth, and it takes 687 of those days to make up one year.  That translates to 1,374 Earth days, or almost four Earth years.  Of that number, orbital winter takes up 365 days, or two whole Earth years.  Orbital summer, by contrast, takes up 59 days in the calendar, or 118 Earth days, or one-third of one Earth year.  Orbital spring lasts 131 days, or 262 Earth days, or almost three-quarters of one Earth year, and orbital autumn lasts 132 days, or 264 Earth days.
Curiously, this world’s seasons aren’t solely elliptical.  It teeters at an axis of 19.7 degrees, lower than even Earth’s lowest axis.  In conventional circumstances, it results in an overall cooler planet with less extreme seasons, but in this scenario, one can't be too sure.
Combining all the detailed descriptions of the various relevant factors, it all boils down to one question--how will the monsoons work on such a supercontinent?  Would they bear any similarity to India's?

Can you add a map to better understand the geography of the area?

I don't have Photoshop anymore.

So the continent could be described as a chevron. Not clear where the point/elbow is, behind the point is however mountainous. The "second highest" mountains are unknown location.

As to creating imagery, There are more image manipulation tools beyond Photoshop. Krita is photshop like. Without imagery or better description I am inclined to say north to south land placement is equal enough to minimize monsoons.
